# syntax error in INSERT INTO statement visual basic

Tags: vb.net

i dont know if this has been answered or not but i'm having problem with a syntax error in insert into statement.
heres my code, i'm using visual basic 2010, and ms access 2010 as my database

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Comprehensive.Form1
Public Class Form2
Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Private Sub RefreshData()
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY ID", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    cnn.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Try
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Open()
        End If


        cmd.Connection = cnn
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Items (Item_Name, Item_Type, Date_Added)" + "'VALUES('" & TextBox1.Text  & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "');'"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        RefreshData()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " - " & ex.Source)
        cnn.Close()
    End Try



End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ShitdataDataSet.Items' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.ItemsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ShitdataDataSet.Items)
    cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=shitdata.mdb;"
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Major [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) problem, and there should be no `'` before VALUES and after the ending `;`.

Comment: You have an extra single quote before your `VALUES` clause, and there should be a space between the close paranthesis in your column list and the `VALUES` keyword, as well as an extra single quote at the end of your statement.

Comment: [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)!!!

Answer (score 1):

The INSERT line contains single quotes not needed before the VALUES keyword AND at the end of the sql statement, remove them

```
 (Item_Name, Item_Type, Date_Added) VALUES(....) 
                                  ^^^          ^^^
```

But as usual, you don't write sql commands in this way.
You should always use a parameterized query ([SQL Injections](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html))

```
    cmd.Connection = cnn
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Items (Item_Name, Item_Type, Date_Added)" & _
                      "VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", TextBox3.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

And, as a last note, keep in mind that if you have a datetime in your table (as it should) for the Date_Added field then you need to convert the textbox3 value to a datetime.

If this is the case, then, I recommend to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217464/trying-to-insert-datetime-now-into-date-time-field-gives-data-type-mismatch-er/16218074#16218074) where the problem of inserting datetime values in access databases has been resolved.

Comment: woah that was fast reply, anyway thanks man, that solves y problem, guess all i have to worry about is the update and delete buttons on the program

Comment: parameterized query? first time i heard that, and my prof did not discuss anything about that, guess i need to do more research other than listening to my teachers

Comment: Absolutely, look at the links given in its comment from [Mr Isaksson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson) or mine for a more formal discussion of the problem (a big one indeed)

Comment: And there is also the problem of parsing text. What happen in a concatenated sql string when TextBox1.Text contains a single quote? Try it and show it to your teacher :-)

Comment: got an error "expression expected" dont know f i did that right

Comment: yeah i noticed that, had to remove the semicolons in it