# OleDb Linq2Sql style table with DateTime will not update

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a MS Access '97 OleDB database, with a table named "MyTable"

```
[Table]
public class MyTable
{
    [Column]
    public DateTime DateStamp;
}
```

I open it up with a `DataContext` object, call `InsertOnSubmit` with a new instance of a `MyTable` with `DateStamp = DateTime.Now`.
Running `SubmitChanges()` causes the following exception:

"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Should DateStamp be a DBDateType or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to insert DateTime.Now into Date/Time field gives "Data type mismatch" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217464/trying-to-insert-datetime-now-into-date-time-field-gives-data-type-mismatch-er)

Comment: the first answer from this one solved it for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217464/trying-to-insert-datetime-now-into-date-time-field-gives-data-type-mismatch-er/16218074#16218074